# How do I add rulers through the entirety of the document in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, divider, rulers

How do I insert a ruler into SSRS report file?

Not just the rulers on the top/side of the page but a line going through the entirety of the file (vertically and horizontally).

Something like this --

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in function to do this specifically, but there are some ways to achieve a similar result. Here are some ideas to try:

- Insert an image of the ruler.
- Insert some 1-inch rectangles.

I find it helpful to adjust the positions of objects using the `Location` values rather than dragging them around. It helps to have nicely rounded values for formatting especially if you plan to export to Excel so the cells line up nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Background Image of a ruler in the Background property of the report's Body.

[image]

I haven't actually done this but see no reason why it wouldn't work as you would want it to.